# AngularJS/Javascript dropdown "onchange" function is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html-select

```
<select name="Connection" class="mdl-button" id="dropConnection" onchange="connectionChange()" ></select>
```

The contents are added automatically from JSON response.Thats working fine.

```
function connectionChange()
{
    var sel = document.getElementById("dropConnection");
    var connectionName = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
  $scope.connectionDetail = response.data.message.connectionDetailses.filter(det => det.connectionId === connectionName);
  console.log($scope.connectionDetail);
}
```

after running the page,when I change the dropdown content its showing error

```
home.html:265 Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
    at connectionChange (home.html:265) // above javascript code.
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (VM4122 home.html:139)
```

Comment: `onchange` is a native javascript event, not an Angular directive `ng-change`. And `connectionChange` is just event handler, not angular `$scope` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
home.html:265 Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
    at connectionChange (home.html:265) // above javascript code.
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (VM4122 home.html:139)
```

Looking at this error it can be inferred that you have not injected `$scope` in your controller. Inject `$scope` in your controller and it will resolve this error.

Check the link here for knowing how to create a controller in AngularJS properly [AngularJS controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.. but still getiing 1 error. "connectionChange" is undefined.

Comment: try to use `ng-change=connectionChange()` and define `$scope.connectionChange = function(){}`